# Max payment by client showing account SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I seem to be having a writers block moment.

I need a query that will return the Max payment, by client and account on a specific date.

2 tables used one for customer and Client data (client 1 has say 50 customers) and the second table for payments received and date.

So I want a table that shows :

```
Client | Account | Paid   | Date
----------------------------------------
   1   | 1234    | £2.99  | 01/11/2012
   2   | 1235    | £4.99  | 08/12/2012
```

hope that makes sense! in my head it should be pretty simple!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports `Common Table Expression` and `Windowing Function`. The query uses `DENSE_RANK()` which gives a rank value according to greatest `Paid` for every `Account`. So the first value is the greatest value and has rank value of `1`. This is the value that you are going to filter.

Assuming the column that links the two tables is `Client`

```
WITH record
AS
(
    SELECT  a.Client, a.Account, b.Paid, b.Date,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Client ORDER BY b.Paid DESC) rn
    FROM    Customer a
            INNER JOIN Data b
                ON a.Client = b.Client
)
SELECT  Client, Account, Paid, Date
FROM    record
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98475/1)
- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Consider the following records (from [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98475/1))

**Customer table**

```
╔════════╦═════════╗
║ CLIENT ║ ACCOUNT ║
╠════════╬═════════╣
║      1 ║ Stack   ║
║      2 ║ Over    ║
║      3 ║ Flow    ║
╚════════╩═════════╝
```

**Data Table**

```
╔════════╦══════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ CLIENT ║ PAID ║              DATE              ║
╠════════╬══════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║      1 ║  123 ║ January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      1 ║  234 ║ January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      1 ║   33 ║ January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      2 ║  674 ║ January, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      2 ║ 2424 ║ January, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      2 ║ 4545 ║ January, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      3 ║   22 ║ January, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      3 ║ 3456 ║ January, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      3 ║  445 ║ January, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
╚════════╩══════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

---

**The result of Joined Table**

```
╔════════╦═════════╦══════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ CLIENT ║ ACCOUNT ║ PAID ║              DATE              ║
╠════════╬═════════╬══════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║      1 ║ Stack   ║  123 ║ January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      1 ║ Stack   ║  234 ║ January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║ << Expected Output
║      1 ║ Stack   ║   33 ║ January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      2 ║ Over    ║  674 ║ January, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      2 ║ Over    ║ 2424 ║ January, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      2 ║ Over    ║ 4545 ║ January, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║ << Expected Output
║      3 ║ Flow    ║   22 ║ January, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      3 ║ Flow    ║ 3456 ║ January, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║ << Expected Output
║      3 ║ Flow    ║  445 ║ January, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
╚════════╩═════════╩══════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

**THE FINAL OUTPUT**

```
╔════════╦═════════╦══════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ CLIENT ║ ACCOUNT ║ PAID ║              DATE              ║
╠════════╬═════════╬══════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║      1 ║ Stack   ║  234 ║ January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      2 ║ Over    ║ 4545 ║ January, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║      3 ║ Flow    ║ 3456 ║ January, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
╚════════╩═════════╩══════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'd just figured out after you posted!!! will keep this as a reminder for the next time!! thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the final output include all Dates? It seems your losing January 1, 4, 5, 7, 9.

Answer (score 0):

This question was quite interesting.
The problem is solved using an aggregate query.

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29256/1/0

```
select d.[Client], c.[Account],
max([Paid])as 'PAID', 
d.[Date] 
from Customer c, Data d where
d.[Client] = c.[Client] 
group by d.[Client],c.[Account],d.[Date];
```

Produces the Results:

```
CLIENT  ACCOUNT PAID    DATE
1   Stack   123 January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000
1   Stack   234 January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000
1   Stack   33  January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000
2   Over    674 January, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000
2   Over    2424    January, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000
2   Over    4545    January, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000
3   Flow    22  January, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000
3   Flow    3456    January, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000
3   Flow    445 January, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

If we had the situation where a Client Could have Many Accounts and we wanted to find the Client-Account with the largest Amount Paid for a specific date we would have to do something more complicated:

```
select *
from Customer c2, Data d2, 
(
select d.[Client],
max([Paid])as 'PAID', 
d.[Date] 
from Customer c, 
Data d 
where
d.[Client] = c.[Client] group by d.[Client],d.[Date]
) subQ
where c2.[client] = d2.[client] and
c2.[client] = subQ.[client] and
d2.[Paid] = subQ.[Paid] and
d2.[Date] = subQ.[Date];
```

As you cannot add additional columns to a query that are not part of the group by - see: http://technicalsmile.blogspot.gr/2011/04/column-is-invalid-in-select-list.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
  Customer.name, 
  Account.name as account_name, 
  [date], 
  max(paid) 
from Data,
     Customer,
     Account
where Data.client = Customer.id
  and Data.account = Account.id
group by Customer.name, Account.name, [date]
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93baf/2